# how to float bootstrap 4 mixed nav items to the right on phone and also desktop

Tags: bootstrap-4

I am trying to achieve this (points 1 and 2):

[image: example]

but without luck with my code.
It seems `navbar-right` has no effect when page is mobile phone sized. 
Any ideas?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/all.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
            MyApp
        </a>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 1</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 2</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <a class="nav-link navbar-right">
            <i class="fa fa-car fa-2x" style="color:red"></i>
        </a>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>
        </div>

        <button class="navbar-right navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
            aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

    </nav>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe `.navbar-right` was removed in Bootstrap 4. I also think that `<form>` elements which are children of `.navbar` automatically align right.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/navbar/#forms